# fatal: unexpected line in .git/packed-refs: ^fea587657bd1ec6b0ff0b201669edc48e2575131?

Tags: git

Good day,

In my web application java project, I am using gerrit server to host my code. And when I push a git tag, I can see my `packed-refs` append some line with caret symbol in front, for example:

```
b9b73aeb23809234c6786e941fbca7b8f6e47959 refs/tags/20200417_1130_SIT
^3648eaf59a435e07afca6e0be755fc75ac39abf4
```

I believe this is normal.

Now I am doing a `Talend` project that using `Github` to host the code. In `Talend Studio`, I push a tag. And then my `packed-refs` file will append new line with something as above.

However, when I use git bash command to type `git tag`, I will hitting error as follow:

```
fatal: unexpected line in .git/packed-refs: #^b91a6a7007ad734090bb0ff5224ab973164095c1?
```

May I know what is happening?